# All office apps crash immediately on server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, 64-bit, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007

I have a brand new windows 2008 server (64 bit) with a brand new installation of Office 2007, fully patched with all windows updates etc.

Every time I try to run any of the office apps it crashes immediately, even in safe mode.

the only remotely useful information I get is:

```
 Exception Code: c0000005
 Exception Data: 00000008
```

If I Run in compatibility mode for windows XP, everything is fine.

Anyone ever seen this before? I've tried turning off DEP but that made no difference either

Thanks

Tim

Comment: Is it office x86 or 64? If 86 did you install saying its 86?

Comment: @MrStatic: There's no such thing as Office x64, except in the upcoming Office 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Could you trace what's going on with Process Monitor from sysinternals ? It's free and you can get it here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

If you send me the trace file, i can look what is generating this error

Answer (score 1):

Check Event Viewer (both Application and System). Test the memory on the server with memtes86+. Search for other logs (search for all files changed in the last few minutes).
Check if you have enough disk space.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the minidump yet? It might give you a very good idea of what's causing the crash (likely a driver). MS has a [KB on how to read minidumps](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315263).

Comment: does office create mini dumps or any dumps at all?

Comment: Ah, office is crashing; when you said "safe mode" I automatically thought you meant Windows was crashing. Sorry, brain fart.